# Looking for a series of short stories that have A.I. spaceships and an exoplanet

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, spaceship, artificial-intelligence

I am looking for a series of short stories that have large spaceships with A.I. that travel over large distances.

One story in the series (that is different from the others) has to do with an exoplanet that is populated with people, has a geothermal energy source, and is taken care of by an A.I. One day the A.I. makes a man (who is bored) fall in love with a girl. The man volunteers to fight in a "war" in order to impress the girl.

Comment: Can you give some details about where and when you read them?

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the short story: "Rite of Passage" by Roger Williams. I first read it many years ago on Kuro5hin. If you are curious, you can find his work at http://localroger.com/

Comment: That's great! You can go [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and merge your accounts and accept this answer ;) That would help future querents.

Comment: [I didn't know how to recover the older account, so I made a new one with the same name... maybe I should ask this in another area, but how can I merge an account I cannot recover? ]

Comment: Vie the ["contact us"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/contact) form? I'm sure people there would be able to help. If not - it's no big deal, just use the account you have access to.

Answer (score 2):

Try the Brainships Series by Anne McCaffery.  I can't remember the exact number of books but I believe the first is THE SHIP WHO SANG.  The Human Capt.was the Braun the ship the Brain.  somewhere in the series one off the Brainships require and  takes over the operation of a planet...
I hope this helps!